# Как передать массив в header php?

Tags: php, http, header

Всем привет, незнаю может вопрос конечно глупый и легкий, но я почему-то не могу найти на него ответ или какие то примеры. Задача состоит в следующем, имеется некая последовательность действий, в частности запись в бд, валидация, и мне нужно, чтобы улучшить юзабилити, передать массив в формате ключ-значение на внешний api без дополнительных действий. Т.е. я могу созать еще 1 форму и при нажатии кнопки она отправит значения на сторонний сервис, но я хотел бы уйти от лишних действий. Я подумал можно ли использовать header в php, как бы использовать редирект и передать параметры которые принимает внешний api, подскажите это возможно? И если да, как передать правильно массив в формате ключ-значение через header?

Comment: А какой смысл просить браузер клиента обратиться на внешний апи? С апи общается сервер. И при чем здесь последовательность действий, запись в БД  и юзабилити? Учись задавать вопросы правильно: во-первых, описывать саму задачу, а не абстрактные рассуждения. и во-вторых, описывать саму задачу, а не свои идеи по её решению. Что за массив, что за апи, в каком формате он принимает данные?

Comment: Не вижу никаких препятствий. Headers - это и есть хранилище ключ - значение. Вы можете добавить почти сколько угодно пар, необходимых для API. Как передавать custom headers через curl php есть огромное множество статей в интернете

Comment: @ArchDemon, чтаем внимательно: "*на внешний api*". При чем здесь "пары значений", которые ты отправляешь в браузер?

Comment: @Ипатьев ну так на внешний апи тоже заголовки можно передать, например тот же ключ доступа. Если я правильно понял, что такое внешний апи.

Comment: @Ипатьев, внимательно прочитал. Автору ничего не мешает отправлять значения в заголовке да хоть из браузера на внешний api. Но его вопрос настолько путанный, что непонятно что и зачем он хочет передавать, как и что это упростит, и причём тут редирект, который как-то нужно использовать. И да, кастомные заголовки можно передавать как из браузера, так и в браузер, как на внешнее/внутренне api, так и из него. Не вижу никаких проблем

Comment: Разъясню немного, попробовал использовать тестовую платежную систему, клиент формирует заявку, она записывается в бд, а дальше, ну как по документации, сформировал форму, с токеном, суммой и паре скрытых полей, которые идентифицируют конкретного клиента, и эта форма отправляется на платежный сервис, я же хочу сделать так, чтобы это происходило в фоновом режиме, то есть, после успешной записи заказа пользователя редиректило на платежку, и все нужные данные из полей естественно были переданы, как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Так я и думал. **НИКАК**,...,  не сделать. **Пользователь должен видеть** что и куда он отправляет. А не кота в мешке покупать, что ты там ему сам нахимичил, сам отправил и сам деньги снял. Это называется юзабилити. А не то что ты там себе напридумывал

Comment: "юзабилити" он придумал. как потехничнее пользователя облапошить

Comment: @ArchDemon "внимательно прочитал", но "вопрос путанный", но "не вижу проблем". В вопросе "как из пхп заставить браузер отправить определённые заголовки куда-то ещё". Ну ладно Жан-Клод, он только учится. Но ты-то тут топчешься уже не первый год. Должен хоть немного представлять где у тебя пхп, а где браузер и кто куда заголовки отправляет

Comment: @Ипатьев не в этом дело, не в подстановке что купить там или еще что, как я понимаю, апи принимает конкретные поля из формы методом пост, т.е. массив, скрытых полей я тоже могу наплодить сколько угодно, я и хочу игнорировать дополнительно нажатие на кнопку которая редиректит пользователя на платежку

Comment: Ага, и ключ от квартиры где деньги лежат. Вот удивительно, этот вопрос относительно часто всплывает. Почему-то люди, которые ни разу в жизни ничего не купили в интернете, пытаются как-то "оптимизировать" этот процесс.

Comment: Вероятно вы просто не работали с платежными сервисами, и не знаете, что чтобы работало, нужно передать uid вашего магазина в скрытом поле, от платежного сервиса, такие параметры как валюта, сумма, и токен клиента или личного кабинета например если имеет место пополнение баланса и другие параметры, в данный момент меня интересует техническая составляющая, как пропустить никому не нужный лишний шаг?

Comment: Ну конечно ты уже знаешь лучше всех, какие шаги лишние. Целых два месяца пишешь свой первый интернет магазин. И целых пол-дня работаешь с тестовой платёжной системой. Куда там остальным

Comment: @Ипатьев В общем адекватного ответа у вас не имеется?

Comment: Чтобы получить адекватный ответ, надо задать адекватный вопрос. А чтобы задать адекватный вопрос сначала надо разобраться, где у тебя пхп, где браузер, а где платёжная система. Чтобы не спрашивать, как тебе из пхп через хидер в платёжную систему запрос отправить.поэтому отложи свой магазинчик на пару месяцев, купи нормальный учебник и учи основы

Comment: Если это не этап оплаты, а этап регистрации заказа в платёжной системе, то вы вполне себе можете воспользоваться любой асинхронной библиотекой (ajax, axios, fetch) и отправить необходимый запрос. Если же это этап оплаты, то лучше снять с себя грех и передать это на сторону платёжной системы. 
@Ипатьев, я прекрасно всё понимаю. Из браузера тоже можно заголовки отправлять средствами js

Comment: @ArchDemon это не этап оплаты, это этап перевода пользователь в интерфейс платежной системы, предполагается, что через него будет производиться оплата (через сервис), для этого нужно передать необходимые параметры... И по поводу отложить инет магазин, я не делаю инет магазин, я учусь, в частности сейчас разбираюсь с интеркассой и тестовым кошельком, который должен при правильном платеже отправлять email - все прошло ок.

Comment: И какие же значения вы пытаетесь автоматически заполнить, чтобы в платёжной системе их не приходилось вводить?

Comment: @ArchDemon как у меня сделано сейчас. Пользователь формирует условный заказ, ему считается сумма, дальше он заполняет тестовую простую форму, после чего записывается инфа в бд, и он переходит на страницу, где нужно нажать кнопку "перейти к оплате", которая отправляет скрытые данные формы платежной системе (id заказа, uid магазина в платежке, сумма и валюта), дальше пользователь переносится на платежную систему и выбирает способ оплаты, в моем случае это тестовая карта, после успешного платежа возвращает платежка успех и должно прийти подтверждение платежа...

Comment: @ArchDemon в этом то и есть вопрос, никому не нужный лишний шаг, который я хотел бы пропустить, чтобы сразу после заполнения формы со своей инфой, пользователь сразу был перемещен на платежный сервис, без лишнего нажатия кнопки, которая просто его редиректит к платежу передавая по апи параметры....

Comment: Мне вот реально интересно. Ты хоть одну вещь когда-нибудь в каком-нибудь интернет-магазине покупал? Хоть раз где-нибудь видел, чтобы какие-то по твоему мнению "лишние" шаги были пропущены?

Comment: @Ипатьев Естественно, скажи пожалуйста, после заполнения данных пользователем и отправки данных в бд (формирование заказа) тебе очень будут важны данные которые ты даже не видишь, например валюта рубли, сумма котораяпредопределилась, или зашифрованный токен заказа или уникальный идентификатор магазина в платежной системе? Ты это даже не увидишь, перед тобой как перед клиентом будет кнопка "Перейти к оплате" нажав на которую ты переходишь на платежную систему...

Comment: Это для пользователя пустые символы, набор знаков, не несущие никакой конструктивной информации, и не передающие какие либо личные данные...

Comment: И где ты это видел?

Comment: У себя я это вижу и не вижу везде, после заполнения форм в любом магазине пользователю предлагается оформить заказ и оплатить, где ты видишь свою корзину, вводишь контактные данные и адрес и нажимаешь оплатить, после чего откроется поле для ввода инфы карты и смс подтверждения, а у меня получается, что я заполняю форму, а потом еще одно действие делаю перед редиректом на внесение данных карты на платежном сервисе

Comment: "сразу открывается" только у самых крупных магазинов, в которых свой процессинг. на них смотреть не надо

Comment: Почему не надо, разве плохо стараться улучшить юзабилити? И после заполнения данных пользователя вместо кнопки "Далее" сразу дать возможность "Перейти к оплате"?

Comment: Ещё раз. ты видел где-то такой вариант? Я понимаю, что все вокруг дебилы, а ты гений юзабилити, пришел совершить революцию в онайн оплатах. Но можешь ответить на простой вопрос - можешь дать ссылку на конкретный интернет-магазин, где сделано так как ты хочешь?

Comment: Ведь если разбить процесс на шаги (у меня) : 1. Формирование заказа и расчет стоимости 2. Заполнение данных о клиенте - >редирект на еще одну страницу где форма формируется из заказа и состоит из скрытых полей, идентификаторов - > нужно нажать кнопку "Перейти к оплате" и 3. Перевод пользователя на платежный сервис. И как я бы хотел сделать:  1. Формирование заказа и расчет стоимости 2. Заполнение данных о клиенте 3. Перейти на оплату в платежный сервис после записи данных о заказе в бд

Comment: Я не знаю конкретного поимера того, что я хочу, в моем конкретном случае есть бессмысленный шаг нажатия на кнопку не меняя данных, которые уже сформированы и скрыты, и этот шаг нажатия на кнопку лишнюю я хотел бы пропустить. А про php я спросил вообще возможно ли это, ибо на сколько я понимаю функция header в пхп как раз создана для работы с заголовками, или это не так?

Comment: моё мнение, что ты расставляешь приоритеты неверно, чем долбаться с пропуском одного шага при заказе и оплате товара, сделал бы что-то более полезное для своего проекта, тудушек совсем нет?

Comment: Ну вот я решаю эти вопросы, нахожусь в процессе изучения вообще разработки и ставлю себе задачи и хочу как то найти решение, в частности понятное дело, что можно и не парится, впринципе с одним шагом все работает, захотел просто более удобным процесс сделать, поэтому и написал, пока есть пару вариантов попробую позже может получится

Comment: Юзабилити в данном случае заключается в четком понимании клиентом своих действий. Не галопом по европам, а четко по шагам.

Comment: Ну да, просто после заполнения данных пользователя хочу кнопку "Далее" заменить на "Перейти к оплате" сразу, уменьшить количество шагов, и чтобы при нажатии на кнопку проверялось успешность записи в бд, и если успешно отправляло пользователя на платежный сервис, где он уже будет вводить данные своих карт, емэйлов и т.д, а если ошибка записи в бд будет, то редирект на еррор пэйдж, с описанием типа "ошибка формирования заказа"

Comment: Развели тут срач. Автору всего лишь нужно было сказать, что вместо перенаправления клиента на страницу с кнопкой "Перейти к оплате", его нужно перенаправлять на страницу платёжного сервиса. Делается это с помощь конструкции `header('Location: адрес_платежного_сервиса_со_всеми_скрытыми_полями');`. Учтите, что функцию `header` нужно вызывать до вывода любого текста клиенту. Если переход на страницу платёжного сервиса делается методом POST, то вам нужно с помощью curl передать все данные платёжному сервису, а потом перенаправить пользователя на полученную от сервиса страницу.

Comment: @ArchDemon садись, два. Именно это автор и хотел, и я ему битый час объяснял что это невозможно. А про курл - это уже совсем днище. Если не понимаешь как оплата работает в теории, то садись и делай на практике. Потом расскажешь, в какой момент до тебя дошло, почему это не работает

Comment: @Ипатьев, садись, два. Не сочтите за рекламу, но интегрировался со сбером. Этапы: 1. запись покупки в базу. 2. регистрация заказа в платёжной системе (с адресами возврата в магазин). 3. Перенаправление на адрес платёжной системы, полученной в пункте 2. 4. Ввод данных для оплаты. 5. Оплата. 6. Перенаправление на страницу магазина. 7. Profit !!!

Comment: @ArchDemon вот теперь, после того как мы выкидываем неграмотное "Если переход на страницу платёжного сервиса делается методом POST" - то да. поскольку никакого "перехода" здесь нет и быть не может, а есть стандартный запрос API, который возвращает код платежа, по которому потом будет производиться подтверждение. Потому что если у нас "переход", то он возвращает не ссылку, а HTML страницу.

Comment: @Ипатьев, ничто не должно останавливать автора от слабоумия и отваги!